# Scanf always returning 0.000000

Tags: c, floating-point, int, printf, scanf

I'm trying to make a simple program to calculate the body mass index, but the scanf(s) always return 0.00000, no matter what i try. I searched everywhere, tried many things,
Thanks to everyone.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {
    float height;
    float initialheight;
    float weight;
    float bmi;
    float nothing;

    printf("What's your weight? ");
    scanf("%lf", &weight);
    printf("%f", &weight);

    printf("What's your height? ");
    scanf("%lf", &initialheight);
    printf("%f", &initialheight);

    height = (initialheight * initialheight);
    printf("%f", &height);

    bmi = (weight / height);
    printf("Your BMI is ");
    printf("%f", &bmi);

    scanf("%f", nothing); //just to keep the program open
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you checking the return value of scanf?

Comment: Compile with warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have to change two things. First, change `printf("%f", &weight)` to `printf("%f", weight)`. And also change `scanf("%lf", &weight)` to `scanf("%f", &weight)` will make your program fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you print a value you dont have to print the adress!

So change this:

```
printf("%f", &weight);
```

to this:

```
printf("%f", weight);
```

So that you actually print the value

An also you have to change `%lf` to `%f` in your scanf

So your program should look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    float height, initialheight, weight, bmi;

    printf("What's your weight?\n>");
    scanf(" %f", &weight);

    printf("%.2f\n\n", weight);

    printf("What's your height?\n>");
    scanf(" %f", &initialheight);

    printf("%.2f\n\n", initialheight);

    height = (initialheight * initialheight);
    bmi = (weight / height)*10000;

    printf("Your BMI is ");
    printf("%.2f\n\n", bmi);

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

As an example with the input:

```
70 and 175
```

The result/ BMI is:

```
22.86
```

Side Note:

```
BMI = mass(kg) / (height(m) * height(m))

BMI = mass(lb) / (height(in) * height(in)) * 703
```